# Google voice search crashing

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-note-2, voice-command, google-voice-actions

The Google voice search crashes after detecting the keyword `ok google`.
If, I tap on the mike button in the search app and do voice search, it works.
What could be the reason behind this app-crash?

Phone: Samsung Galaxy Note II (GT-N7100)
OS: 4.4.2 KitKat. (Rooted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last, I found a solution.

The problem was with the entry in sports section in Google Now. It can also happen with entry in stocks according to [this article](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/05/13/psa-removing-or-adding-teams-or-stocks-in-google-now-currently-causes-it-to-crash-endlessly/).
Resetting the Google Now data fixed the issue.

Steps I did:

1. Open Google Now and click the magic wand on the bottom right which opens a Customize Google Now screen.
2. Click the sports section and remove all.
3. Do the same for stocks.
4. Open settings >> Application >> Google search, and tap clear data.
5. Open Google Now, go to settings and disable Google Now.
6. Restart the device.
7. Open Google Now, Follow the instructions.

I also turned off audio history from the voice menu of google now settings.
This [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/help/resolved-reset-google-t1939485) helped me to fix this issue.

After the reset all my cards started to appear again except the sports. Data was there in  for all sub menus except sports and stocks in the Customize Google Now screen.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the Google launcher which has the Voice command operations as well as the Cards which you have mentioned  (I can't assure you that this answer will work because the root of the phone may hamper the application working but still you can try as these steps are common for all).

And yes you will lose the cards as you are deleting the data but you will not loose if you clearing cache.Clearing cache memory is no where related to any file getting deleted .

Cache memory is just a temporary storage which is used to speed up the loading of any application.If you clear the cache memory then your app may load slow only the first time later it loads fast.

Coming to the voice search crashing after "OK Google" could be related with your mic problem or just a small software bug.Follow these steps to pin-point the main reason of the issue

First enable the speech output from settings>Voice>Speech output to make sure it is really detecting OK Google and not something else.If it's detecting correctly then your microphone is correct.

Second after enabling the speech output you need to 1)force stop then 2)clear the cache.

Third make sure the area around the mic is clean and is free of any obstruction (the mic could contain small and minute dust particles which need to be cleaned only by trained professionals, covered by some accessory).

After that you shall be able to perform voice search directly without manually touching the microphone.

If you still have the problem then you need to get in touch with the Support team which is there in the play store bottom of the app page.

Comment: I am using the google search application, which is there in play-store as well. Clearing the cache didn't work. Voice search works unless invoked by the "Okay Google" command.

Comment: To be precise, the application hangs up at the recognition stage.

Comment: Did u try a force stop + clearing cache? Seems the root is causing the prob

Comment: Yes, I did a force stop + clear cache.

Comment: then it's the root which is causing the interference with the application

Comment: It was working until last week. I rooted my phone around 6 months back.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I fix it was to uninstall the updates. After resetting it back up the voice searches started working again.